# Use external multi modal JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I would like to utilize the external [multi modal](https://github.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal) Github script in meteor to run with bootstrap modals taken from a meteor bootstrap package I have installed on my app. There is no meteor package for this. I'm using the $.getScript() jQuery function to get the source JS file. It is set up like such:

```
Meteor.startup( function () {
    $.getScript("https://cdn.rawgit.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal/master/multi-step-modal.js");
});
```

Unfortunately when I include this, the file from the URL gets loaded but the modal functionality doesn't work. I believe that all the HTML is correct. Is there an alternative way to include third party libraries? Could the library possibly be broken?

Comment: How are you invoking the modal functionality? Are you expecting `$.getScript` to be synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Meteor.startup( function () 
{
    $.getScript("https://cdn.rawgit.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal/master/multi-step-modal.js",function()
    {
        // Here the script is loaded and you can use it's functions
    });
});
```

Comment: That is simpler than I had imagined. I just needed to use the callback function. Thanks